# How to invoke Action set in property of Moq input parameter

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have the following method in a ViewModel.

```
public void ViewModelMethod()
        {
            UserDialogs.Confirm(new ConfirmConfig
            {
                Message = "Dialog message",
                OnConfirm = (result) =>
                {
                    if (result)
                    {
                        AnotherService.Method();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

In my tests I have the UserDialogsMock and AnotherServiceMock. I'm trying to setup the UserDialogsMock like below.

```
UserDialogsMock.Setup(s => s.Confirm(It.IsAny<ConfirmConfig>()))
                .Callback((ConfirmConfig confirmConfig) => confirmConfig.OnConfirm(true));
```

How to verify that AnotherServiceMock.Method is invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `AnotherServiceMock` is injected, just verify it as normal:

```
AnotherServiceMock.Verify(s => s.Method(), Times.Once());
```

---

Here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that works for me:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    using System;
    using Moq;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    public class MoqCallbackTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Mock<IAnotherService> mockAnotherService = new Mock<IAnotherService>();
            Mock<IUserDialogs> mockUserDialogs = new Mock<IUserDialogs>();

            mockUserDialogs.Setup(s => s.Confirm(It.IsAny<ConfirmConfig>()))
                           .Callback((ConfirmConfig confirmConfig) => confirmConfig.OnConfirm(true));

            SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest(mockUserDialogs.Object, 
                                                                  mockAnotherService.Object);
            systemUnderTest.ViewModelMethod();
            mockAnotherService.Verify(p => p.Method(), Times.Never());
        }

        public interface IAnotherService
        {
            void Method();
        }

        public interface IUserDialogs
        {
            void Confirm(ConfirmConfig config);
        }

        public class ConfirmConfig
        {
            public Action<bool> OnConfirm { get; set; }
        }

        public class SystemUnderTest
        {
            readonly IAnotherService anotherService;
            readonly IUserDialogs userDialogs;

            public SystemUnderTest(IUserDialogs userDialogs, IAnotherService anotherService)
            {
                this.userDialogs = userDialogs;
                this.anotherService = anotherService;
            }

            public void ViewModelMethod()
            {
                userDialogs.Confirm(new ConfirmConfig { OnConfirm = result =>
                {
                    if (result)
                        anotherService.Method();
                } });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I do but it doesn't work because the UserDialogs accepts a parameter of type ConfirmConfig which has a property OnConfirm of type Action that is never invoked when testing. How to make the USerDialogsMock to invoke any ConfirmConfig OnConfirm Action?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works as expected for me, so there must be something missing from your code sample that is in your actual system.

Comment: Oh man, these days, forgot to call the method that sets up the actual setup of the UserDialogsMock setup!